# BizTalk XSLT Transformation Script Nested Loops

Tags: xslt, dictionary, transform, biztalk

I am pretty much new to BizTalk, have been working on a solution and wasnot able to get the transformation done with built-in functoids (Loop, table loops etc. etc.)

Seems like it can be easily done with Inline XSLT script, I tried that getting orchestration error probably something wrong with the script.

Can someone assist me with that?
Thanks Much
Ramsey

This is the map: 
I want to transfor data If Part_0 PolicyNumber = Part_1 PolicyNumber
http://psrathoud.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/2014-09-09-08_43_37-map.jpg

and below is the script

```html
<xsl:template name="ValidateTransactionData">
 <!-- Loop MessagePart_0 -->
 <xsl:for-each select="InputMessagePart_0/s1:MergedINTWAW_Root/Merged_DATA">
 <!-- Create "Matching_DATA" record in the output message for each matching transaction-->
   <Matched_DATA>
   <xsl:variable name="s0_Source" select="Source"/>
   <xsl:variable name="s0_Insured" select="Insured"/>
   <xsl:variable name="s0_PremiumAmount" select="PremiumAmount"/>
   <xsl:variable name="s0_LongPolicy" select="LongPolicyNumber"/>
  
   <!-- Copy transaction details from InputMessagePart_0 to the output message-->
   <Source>
    <xsl:value-of select="Source" />
    </Source>
     
    <Insured>
    <xsl:value-of select="Insured" />
    </Insured>
    
    <PremiumAmount>
    <xsl:value-of select="PremiumAmount" />
    </PremiumAmount>
    
    <LongPolicyNumber>
    <xsl:value-of select="LongPolicyNumber" />
    </LongPolicyNumber >
   
    <!-- Loop InputMessagePart_1 and validate matching long policy number --> 
    <xsl:for-each select="../../../InputMessagePart_1/s1:TAM_Root/TAM_DATA">
     <xsl:if test="string(LongPolicyNumber)=$s0_LongPolicyNumber">
      
      <Source><xsl:value-of select="Source" /></Source>
      <Insured><xsl:value-of select="Insured" /></Insured>
      <PremiumAmount><xsl:value-of select="PremiumAmount" /></PremiumAmount>
      <LongPolicyNumber><xsl:value-of select="LongPolicyNumber" /></LongPolicyNumber >
      
     </xsl:if>    
    </xsl:for-each > 
    <xsl:value-of select="./text()" />   
   
   </Matched_DATA >
   <xsl:value-of select="./text()" />
 
 </xsl:for-each>
 <xsl:value-of select="./text()" />
 
</xsl:template >
```

Comment: Can you please point out which error you are getting please?

Comment: General note: Most instances of xsl:for-each would produce better stylesheets if they were replaced with xsl:apply-template and suitable templates written. You've got a nonprocedural language here; take advantage of it.

Comment: Hi Kesham, Did not take too long to figure it out in the second loop for the second source message in "s1:TAM_Root/TAM_DATA" replaced the s1 with s0. That fixed it.